# Beta-Binomial Pmf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, beta-function

Blitzstein, Introduction to Probability (2019 2 ed), p 58, Example 8.5.3 (Beta-Binomial PMF).
[image]

Transitioning from the second last line to the last line confuses me. Did I miss anything here?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Look up the beta function. This is a standard integral *definition*

Comment: It is unclear what confuses you because there is nothing strange except they are using the definition $B(x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} dt.$